# Merging 2 dataframes and sorting by datetime Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to produce a code where it creates an additional table to the dataframe `data`. The new dataframe `data2` will have the following changes:

- label will be `New` instead of `Old`
- `col1`'s last index will be deleted
- `col2`'s first index will be deleted
- `date` will be first index will be deleted and all date values will
  be subtracted by 1 minute

Then I want to concatenate the two data frames to make one data frame called `merge` I want to sort the dataframe by `dates`. Since the first index of `data2` is dropped the order of `merge` should be in order of `label`: `New, Old, New, Old`. How can I subtract 1 minute from `date_mod` and merge the two data frames in order of dates?

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'col1': [4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 6], 'col2': [6, 2, 1, 7, 3, 5, 3, 3, 9], 
     'label':['Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old','Old'],
     'date': ['2022-01-24 10:07:02', '2022-01-27 01:55:03', '2022-01-30 19:09:03', '2022-02-02 14:34:06',
              '2022-02-08 12:37:03', '2022-02-10 03:07:02', '2022-02-10 14:02:03', '2022-02-11 00:32:25',
              '2022-02-12 21:42:03']}

data = pd.DataFrame(d)

'''
Additional Dataframe
label will have New 
'col1'`s last index will be deleted
'col2'`s first index will be deleted 
'date' will be first index will be deleted and all date values will be subtracted by 1 minute
'''

a = data['col1'].drop(data['col1'].index[-1])
b = data['col2'].drop(data['col2'].index[0])
# subtract the date_mod by 1 minute 
date_mod = pd.to_datetime(data['date'][1:])


data2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a,'col2':b,
'label':['New','New','New','New','New','New','New','New'],
'date': date_mod})
'''
Merging data and data2 
Sort by 'date' 
Should go in order as Old, New, Old, New ...
The length of the columns are 1 less than of data bc of the dropped indexes 
'''
merge=pd.merge(data,displayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way I think off, - place all adjustments into the function and apply to the copy of the original dataframe, later simply concat and sort:

```
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date) # converting column date str values to datetime to deduct 1minute later

def adjust_data(df):
    df['col1'] = df['col1'].drop(df['col1'].index[-1])
    df['col2'] = df['col2'].drop(df['col2'].index[0])
    df.date = df.date - pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)  # subtract the datetime by 1 minute
    df.label = df.label.replace('Old','New') # change values in the column "label"


data2 = data.copy()
adjust_data(data2) # apply function to data2

# concat both dataframes and sort by column "date"
merge = pd.concat([data,data2], axis=0).sort_values(by=['date']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(merge)
```

out:

```
    col1  col2 label                date
0    4.0   NaN   New 2022-01-24 10:06:02
1    4.0   6.0   Old 2022-01-24 10:07:02
2    5.0   2.0   New 2022-01-27 01:54:03
3    5.0   2.0   Old 2022-01-27 01:55:03
4    2.0   1.0   New 2022-01-30 19:08:03
5    2.0   1.0   Old 2022-01-30 19:09:03
6    2.0   7.0   New 2022-02-02 14:33:06
7    2.0   7.0   Old 2022-02-02 14:34:06
8    3.0   3.0   New 2022-02-08 12:36:03
9    3.0   3.0   Old 2022-02-08 12:37:03
10   5.0   5.0   New 2022-02-10 03:06:02
11   5.0   5.0   Old 2022-02-10 03:07:02
12   1.0   3.0   New 2022-02-10 14:01:03
13   1.0   3.0   Old 2022-02-10 14:02:03
14   1.0   3.0   New 2022-02-11 00:31:25
15   1.0   3.0   Old 2022-02-11 00:32:25
16   NaN   9.0   New 2022-02-12 21:41:03
17   6.0   9.0   Old 2022-02-12 21:42:03
```